# Rails singular resource, where does the ID come from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a Rails 6 app and as resource hotel.
My user model has a `belongs_to` hotel (hotel_id) column.

No I want to create a singular resource where a user can access its hotel directly as mentioned here:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources

So I did

`resource :hotel` which maps to hotels#show

The idea is that I don't need to have a link hotel/ID and instead just have /hotel

But now, how does my hotels controller know which hotel to load? I assumed that it would take it from the user table but instead I get

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

which means that there is no @hotel in my view.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you please include the content of your routes files as well as your hotels controller.

Comment: You need something like `@hotel = current_user.hotel` in your controller action

Answer (score 1):

You need nested routes... so in config/routes.rb you need:

```rb
resources :users do
  resource :hotel
end
```

Then examine the route set (e.g. from the rails console do `rails routes`) and you'll see a set of routes that include something like this:

```rb
user_hotel GET /users/:id/hotel  hotels/show
```

do you see the :id parameter buried in the url?

Then in the hotels controller show method, the user's id is found in the params hash. So you can find the hotel like this:

```rb
class HotelsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    user = User.find(user_params(:id))
    @hotel = user.hotel
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:id)
  end
end
```